# How to get the names of all classes that implements a specific interface from a dll

Tags: .net, .net-core, reflection, blazor-server-side

How can I get the names of all classes that implements a specific interface from a dll. I am trying to port a legacy .Net Windows Form application to a Blazor Server app, and I am running in to a problem where the old code does not work anymore. Can anyone explain how this can be achieved? Below is the old code that throws an exception "Could not load file or assembly 'XXX, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified."

```
    class AssemblyLoader : MarshalByRefObject
    {
         public AssemblyLoader()
         { }

         public List<string> Load(string AssemblyFilePath)
         {
            var SelectedAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(AssemblyFilePath);

            var Types = GetTypesSafely(SelectedAssembly);

            var FilteredTypes = Types.Where(x => x.GetInterface("ITestNode") != null && !x.IsAbstract);

            List<string> TestNodes = new List<string>();

            foreach (Type FilteredType in FilteredTypes)
            {
                TestNodes.Add(FilteredType.FullName);
            }

            return TestNodes;
        }

        private IEnumerable<Type> GetTypesSafely(Assembly SelectedAssembly)
        {
           try
           {
            return SelectedAssembly.GetTypes();
           }
           catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
           {
            return ex.Types.Where(x => x != null);
           }
       }
    }


    main()
    {
        AppDomainSetup DomainSetup = new AppDomainSetup();
        DomainSetup.ShadowCopyFiles = "true";

        var Domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("loader", null, DomainSetup);

        var Handle = Domain.CreateInstanceFrom(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, typeof(AssemblyLoader).FullName);

        AssemblyLoader Loader = Handle.Unwrap() as AssemblyLoader;

        var Types = Loader.Load(@"C:\MyAssembly.dll");

        AppDomain.Unload(Domain);

        return Types;
    }
```

Comment: Try `Assembly.LoadFile("path_to_DLL").GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom(t))`.

Comment: @Enigmativity This gives me exception "Could not load file or assembly 'XXX, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.". One thing to point out is that the library I am trying to load is a .net framework 4.6

Comment: Anyone care to explain the down vote?

Comment: Keep trying with the `Assembly.Load*` methods. They should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways I use.

1. Using Visual Studio - assuming your code can load in visual studio 2019+ and currently compiles (you may need targeting packs if not). Go to the interface, right click and 'Go To Implementation' < this will load all references that visual studio can see.
2. Using NotePad++ or some other text edit with a good "search in files" feature
   Choose find in files, target your src directory and search for the interface
   using `: IYourInterface` and `, IYourInterface` in 2 independent searches.

Option 1 is the best and easiest but often I need to use number 2 where not all source projects were represented in the visual studio solution and thus would not be found in search results.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I need this information at runtime on my server. I have updated my question.